# Install old version of firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, installation, redhat

I want to install Firefox 24.2.0 in Scientific Linux environment. I have tried `firefox-24.5.0-1.mga4.x86_64.rpm`, but it did not work. 
What is the correct linux command for that?

Answer (score 1):

Scientific Linux uses `yum` to install packages. It can download these for you, but if you already have the correct Firefox downloaded you can do:

```
yum install firefox-24.5.0-1.mga4.x86_64.rpm
```

You can use `man yum` for more details or browse the [man page online.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html)

Comment: Actually I already have Mozilla Firefox 31.6.0 , but due to some issue i need older version of Firefox. I tried sudo yum install firefox-24.5.0-1.mga4.x86_64.rpm , but this is throwing error [ No package firefox-24.5.0-1.mga4.x86_64.rpm available.]

Answer (score 1):

I found this command "yum downgrade firefox" useful to downgrade firefox version in Scientific Linux environment.